# How can I resize an icon in the custom search suggestion?

Tags: android, image, search-suggestion

I have an application implementing search with suggestions.
The suggestions are displaying an icon for each result, using the `SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1` field for the cursor generation.

I would like to reduce the size of the images displayed as icons. But when I do this, the image is also reduced in the suggestions.

How can I keep a fixed size of the image in the suggestions, whatever the original size or the density are?